# Permissions for Apache and FTPd users

Tags: permissions, ftp, apache-httpd

I'd like advice about permissions on directories and files on a web/ftp server.

Here is my situation:

Debian Server with those user:group

- `userme:userme` for SSH
- `www-data:www-data` for apache/php
- `ftpuser:ftpgroup` for pure-ftpd

File system :

```
-[/srv/data_disk]
    -[Websites]
        -[site1.tld]
            -...
        -[site2.tld]
            -...
    -[Webapps]
        -[App1]
            -...
        -[App2]
            -...
        -config1.php
        -config1.php
```

Explanation:

- Files and dirirectories in `siteX.tld` will be uploaded by ftpuser.
- There is a "upload" subdir in `siteX.tld` where `www-data` will be able to create directories and write files.
- Ftpuser should be able to delete those files created by `www-data`.
- `AppX` directories are created by `userme` in ssh
- they should be read by `www-data` (with a special directory where apache should be able to create/delete files)
- And be accessible by `ftpuser` in read-only mode (for remote updates purposes)

What I thought to do (but I need confirmation that it is a good practice) is make:

- `ftpuser` => member of `ftpgroup` AND `www-data` group
- `www-data` => member of `www-data` group AND `ftpgroup` AND `userme` group
- `userme` => member of `userme` group AND `www-data` group

And then I will `chmod` as follows :

```
-[/srv/data_disk]      => userme:userme 700
    -[Websites]       
        -[site1.tld]    => ftpuser:ftpgroup 750
            -...       
                => ftp uploaded dirs/files = ftpuser:ftpgroup 750 
                => apache uploaded dirs/files = www-data:www-data 770 

    -[Webapps]      => userme:userme 750
        -[App1]      => userme:userme 755
            -...
                => ssh uploaded dirs/files = userme:userme 755 
                => apache created files = www-data:www-data 775
```

Does it sounds safe to you? Ftpusers are chrooted so as apache...